# How can I join multiple tables on the same auto generated integer from one "table"?

Tags: sql, join, random, hana

I want to create a random selected cross-joined table which auto increments its own id and joins on it.
Let's say my tables looking like this.

Person

```
Firstname, Lastname 

Hans      | Müller
Joachim   | Bugert

Address
City, Street, StreetNumber
Hamburg | Wandsbeckerstr. | 2
Berlin  | Konradstraße    | 13
```

Now I want to join the tables with a auto generated ID and they should be random selected.
The final table should look like this

```
ID,Firstname,Lastname, City, Street, StreetNumber
1 |Hans|Bugert|Berlin|Wandsbeckerstr|2
2|Joachim|Müller|Hamburg|Konradstraße | 13
```

What I already tried or used:

Here I auto-generate the ID where I want to join the tables on

```
select GENERATED_PERIOD_START as ID FROM SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1,1,10)
```

The problem is cross join and inner join isn't working for me because it always joins everything with everything or its not joining on the same ID.

```
SELECT Person."Firstname", Person."Lastname", Address."City",Address."Street", Address."StreetNumber"

FROM 
(   select GENERATED_PERIOD_START as ID FROM SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1,1,10)

) autoGenID
inner JOIN
(select "Firstname" ,"Lastname" FROM Person ORDER BY RAND()) Person

inner JOIN 
(select "City", "Street", "StreetNumber", FROM Address  ORDER BY RAND()) Address

JOIN ON autoGenID."ID"=?????
```

Here is my problem I can't just select random data and select that on my auto generated ID.

Thanks for your help or ideas how to solve this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT p."Firstname", p."Lastname", a."City", a."Street", a."StreetNumber"
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) as seqnum
      FROM Person p
     ) p JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) as seqnum
      FROM Address a
     ) a
     ON p.seqnum = a.seqnum;
```

Comment: @Schwenk & GordonLinoff There's no point in randomizing both inputs to the join.

Comment: @philipxy . . . That is true, but `seqnum` needs to be calculated in both subqueries so there is no harm in randomizing it for both.